# How to compile java class with inner classes?

Tags: java, javac

I need to compile a java class that has multiple inner classes (or nested). Example:
Myclass.java
Myclass$sub1.class
Myclass$sub2.class
Myclass$sub2$subsub.class

I need to compile (command line, oracle javac) the file Myclass.java, using the compiled inner class files.

How can this be done? I tried the -sourcepath option, with no luck.

Thanks

Comment: `javac MyClass.java` -- (Is this a trick question?)

Comment: no it's not. using javac MyClass.java i get errors on the references of the nested classes!

Comment: What errors are you getting? Post them.

Comment: error: Cannot find symbol. Example:    public static boolean initialize(SUBCLASS.SUBSUBCLASS t)
                                             ^
  symbol:   class SUBSUB
  location: class SUBCLASS
r\cbri\kern\int\MyCLass.java:114: error: cannot find symbol

Comment: This sounds like a problem with how you're trying to refer to classes in your code rather than the compiler failing to see nested classes. An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would let someone point out your exact problem.

Comment: That's what's known as a compile error.

Answer (score 9):

You compile a source *file*, not a source *class*. Any classes, including nested ones, in that source file are compiled. No special effort required.

Comment: i want to compile Myclass.java (source), BUT the nested classes are already compiled (Myclass$sub1.class Myclass$sub2.class Myclass$sub2$subsub.class)

Comment: They'll be overwritten if they're in the output directory of the compiler. If you want to use these existing ones instead of the compiled ones for whatever reason, then either replace the compiled class files with the existing ones after compiling or else run `java` with the existing ones on your classpath before the compiled ones. The first matching class wins on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

```
javac MyClass.java
```

Just compile the source file it will automatically compile the inner classes as well.

Answer (score 0):

The direct and striaght way would be to use
javac Myclass.java

Please make sure to check the modifiers being used incase you are experiencing errors while referencing the inner classes.
This could be helpful :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70358/2908301